# Deny access permissions - apache, linux

Tags: linux, apache, permissions

How can I deny access permission to an entire folder except one file?
For example, my `DocumentRoot` is `"/var/www/html"` and there I have a folder called `example`. In there, there are many files and one of them is `index.php`. So I want to give access permission only to this file, and deny access permissions to the other files in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try something like this into your apache configuration (server `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` file) ?

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/example">
   <FilesMatch index.php*> 
      Order allow,deny 
      Allow from all 
   </FilesMatch> 
   Order deny,allow 
   Deny from all 
</Directory>
```

Comment: Yeah, this direction to solve the problem. I also had to use this (in `.htaccess`):
`<Files index.php>
require valid-user
</Files>`
for example